# Error When implementing a circular Queue?

Tags: c++, queue

I had to implement a circular queue for class.  The program properly Enqueues and Dequeues when I test it. But whenever I create a new object and set it equal to another, everything prints out correctly, but it crashes at the end, with an error:

```
Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead -> nBlockUse)
```

I ran the debugger and it says the problem is in a line in the Dequeue function. Here is That function.

```
void CQUEUE::Dequeue()
{
if(Isempty())
{
    cout << "Queue is  empty, nothing to delete." << endl;
    return;
}

if((!Isempty()) && (front == back)) //When there is only 1 item in the queue
{                                   // front and back will point to the same node
    delete front;                   //but it wont be null because of that 1 item
    front = back = 0;   
    return;
}

qnode *p = front;
front = front -> next;
delete p;//<----------DEBUGGER POINTS HERE**************
front -> prev = back;
return;

}
```

Like I said, the program works fine until I create a new object and do this

```
 CQUEUE j = k;//Any Enqueues and Dequeues after this work, but it crashes
```

Here is the copy constructor incase that is the problem?

```
CQUEUE::CQUEUE(CQUEUE & original)//Will not compile if I put Const 
{                               //in the parameter for some reason
front = back = 0;           //So I took it out
(*this) = original;
front -> prev = back;
back -> next = front;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your copy constructor you do the following:

```
(*this) = original;
```

The means that your `front` pointers in `CQUEUE j` and `CQUEUE k` both point to the *same* memory.

When `void CQUEUE::Dequeue()` is called for both `j` and `k`, `delete p;` **double** deletes the memory, resulting in a crash.

Also, your copy constructor must be declared as `const`. `CQUEUE::CQUEUE(const CQUEUE& original)`. Without more code is hard to say, but in your copy constructor you need to make deep copies of the pointers (allocate memory using `new`). Reading [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) might help.